# Checkbox in NSTableView column header

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I need to add one checkbox in NSTableView column header.
i am able to add checkbox in all rows for the above column. but i need at the column header level. i need to do a selectall functionality, but unable to add one checkbox at table header level. Any sample code or ideas will be helpful.

Thanks,
Subrat

Comment: It starts with subclassing NSTableHeaderCell. See if this gets you started in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753282/modifying-table-headers-on-mac

Answer (score 2):

Create subclass of `NSButtonCell`

```
@interface CheckboxHeaderCell : NSButtonCell {
    NSButtonCell *cellCheckBox;
    NSColor *bkColor;
}

-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;
-(void)setBkColor:(NSColor *)color;
-(BOOL)getState;
-(void)onClick;

@end  

@implementation CheckboxHeaderCell

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        bkColor = nil;

        cellCheckBox = [[ NSButtonCell alloc] init];
        [cellCheckBox setTitle:@""];
        [cellCheckBox setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
        [cellCheckBox setBordered:NO];
        [cellCheckBox setImagePosition:NSImageRight];
        [cellCheckBox setAlignment:NSLeftTextAlignment];
        [cellCheckBox setObjectValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];

        [cellCheckBox setControlSize:NSSmallControlSize];
        [cellCheckBox setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont
                                                        smallSystemFontSize]]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [cellCheckBox release];
    [bkColor release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    [cellCheckBox setTitle:title];
}

-(void)setBkColor:(NSColor *)color
{
    [color retain];
    [bkColor release];
    bkColor = color;
}

-(BOOL)getState
{
    return [[cellCheckBox objectValue] boolValue];
}

-(void)onClick
{
    BOOL state = ![[cellCheckBox objectValue] boolValue];
    [cellCheckBox setObjectValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:state]];
}

- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    if (bkColor != nil)
        [cellCheckBox setBackgroundColor:bkColor];

    [cellCheckBox drawWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView] ;
}

@end
```

How to use:

```
CheckboxHeaderCell *mHeaderCell = [[CheckboxHeaderCell alloc] init];
    NSTableColumn *checkBoxColumn = [mOutlineView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"state"];
    [checkBoxColumn setHeaderCell:mHeaderCell];  

- (void)tableView: (NSTableView *)tableView didClickTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
{
    NSLog(@"didClickTableColumn");
    CheckboxHeaderCell *headerCell = [tableColumn headerCell];
    [headerCell onClick];
}
```

Comment: With new xcode , its possible to directly drag checkbox inside tableview header cell.

Comment: what version of Xcode? It doesn't seem like this works with Xcode 5.

Comment: This doesn't work. For an explanation of why see my answer.

Comment: @JonathanMitchell you can also drag and drop checkbox in table view header cell.

Comment: @JonathanMitchell I am facing issue with password protected pdf files. last opened file is visible in background of password field and password  field is visible on normal pdf file. Its reproducible on 10.12.4 beta 1 also. Can you please help me out ?

Comment: @ParagBafna Note sure that I know what is going on there. Apparently the 10.12 PDF implementation utilises some/all of the iOS PDF codebase.

Comment: @JonathanMitchell I am able to fix this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173471/password-field-not-visible-on-password-protected-pdf/42173506#42173506

Comment: Swift 5 version, macOS 11.0 tested: https://gist.github.com/Lessica/176c2314336fc861398de1e1045aa368

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom `NSCell` instance doesn't work for the simple reason that the `NSTableHeaderView` that co-ordinates the `NSHeaderCell` instances handles all of the mouse event processing. Hence cell buttons in table headers never respond to mouse events.

The solution is to add the required `NSControl` instances to a custom `NSTableHeaderView`. The custom subclass can be set on the table view in IB. Controls are added to identified table columns like so:

```
[(BPTableHeaderView *)self.tableView.headerView addSubview:self.passwordTableHeaderButton
                                          columnIdentifier:@"password"
                                                 alignment:NSLayoutAttributeRight];
```

Any `NSView` instance can  be added to a column header though is  likely that adding an `NSControl` instance will be most common.

`NSTableHeaderView` subclass.

```
@interface BPTableHeaderView : NSTableHeaderView

- (void)addSubview:(NSView *)view columnIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier alignment:(NSLayoutAttribute)alignment;

@end

@interface BPTableHeaderView()

// collections
@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSDictionary *> *store;

// primitives
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL subviewsVisible;

@end

@implementation BPTableHeaderView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
         [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)commonInit
{
    _subviewsVisible = YES;
    _store = [NSMutableDictionary new];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Accessors

- (void)setSubviewsVisible:(BOOL)subviewsVisible
{
    if (_subviewsVisible == subviewsVisible) return;

    _subviewsVisible = subviewsVisible;

    for (NSString *identifier in self.store.allKeys) {
        NSDictionary *info = self.store[identifier];
        NSView *view = info[@"view"];
        view.hidden = !_subviewsVisible;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Drawing

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if (self.draggedColumn != -1 || self.resizedColumn != -1) {
        [self layoutSubviews];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View management

- (void)addSubview:(NSView *)view columnIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier alignment:(NSLayoutAttribute)alignment
{
    self.store[identifier] = @{@"view" : view, @"alignment" : @(alignment)};
    [self addSubview:view];
    self.needsLayout = YES;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Layout

- (void)layout
{
    [super layout];
    [self layoutSubviews];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    for (NSString *identifier in self.store.allKeys)
    {
        // info
        NSDictionary *info = self.store[identifier];
        NSView *view = info[@"view"];
        NSLayoutAttribute alignment = [info[@"alignment"] integerValue];

        // views and cells
        NSTableColumn *column = [self.tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:identifier];
        NSTableHeaderCell *headerCell = column.headerCell;
        NSInteger idx = [self.tableView.tableColumns indexOfObject:column];
        if (idx == NSNotFound) continue;

        // rects
        NSRect headerRect = [self headerRectOfColumn:idx];
        NSRect sortIndicatorRect = NSZeroRect;
        if (column.sortDescriptorPrototype) {
            sortIndicatorRect = [headerCell sortIndicatorRectForBounds:headerRect];
        }

        // position view
        NSPoint viewOrigin = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
        CGFloat y = (headerRect.size.height - view.frame.size.height)/2;
        CGFloat xDelta = 3;
        if (alignment == NSLayoutAttributeLeft) {
            viewOrigin = NSMakePoint(headerRect.origin.x + xDelta, y);
        }
        else {
            viewOrigin = NSMakePoint(headerRect.origin.x + headerRect.size.width - view.frame.size.width - sortIndicatorRect.size.width - 5, y);
        }
        [view setFrameOrigin:viewOrigin];
    }

}
@end
```