# Password field not visible on password protected pdf

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, macos-sierra

I am using PDF kit framework to display/Edit pdf files. Its broken badly on macOS 10.12. Sometimes password protected files do not display password field and sometimes password field is visible in normal file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to fix this using undocumented APIs. Its issue related to hide/unhide password view.

```
/*
 From class dump of pdf kit
 @interface PDFPasswordViewController : NSViewController
 {
 NSTextField *_passwordField;
 NSTextField *_passwordPrompt;
 NSTextField *_passwordInstruction;
 NSView *_passwordView;
 PDFView *_pdfView;
 }

 - (void).cxx_destruct;
 - (void)_commonInit;
 - (void)passwordEntered:(id)arg1;
 - (void)setPDFView:(id)arg1;
 - (void)loadView;

 @end
 */

/*
 @private
 PDFViewPrivate* _private;
 Available in PDFView.h file
 */
id PDFViewPrivate = [self.pdfView valueForKey:@"_private"];
if (PDFViewPrivate)
{
    NSViewController *passwordViewController = [PDFViewPrivate valueForKey:@"passwordViewController"];
    NSView *passwordView = [passwordViewController valueForKey:@"_passwordView"];
    if (self.pdfView.document.isLocked)
    {
        NSTextField *passwordField = [passwordViewController valueForKey:@"_passwordField"];
        // Reset last password
        [passwordField setStringValue:@""];
        // Add password view
        passwordView.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        passwordView.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

`PDFPasswordViewController` is only available on 10.12

Comment: Apple bug id is 30479684