# How to change a height of NSTableHeaderCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm making a table view which has a custom table header. So, I really want to change a height of the header. It's not easier work than I think. How can I make a success?

In addition, I try to make a subclass of NSTableHeaderCell, and override drawInteriorWithFrame:inView: method to draw anything. How can I change a frame's rect to be passed to the method. If I control this rect, I think the I'll reach my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by setting the frame of the header.

```
 NSTableHeaderView *tableHeaderView = [[NSTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 120, 60)];
 [_tableView setHeaderView:tableHeaderView];
```

Comment: I already tried to use the code that you suggest. It affected to a height of a NSTableHeaderView, but it didn't affected to a height of a NSTableHeaderCell.

Comment: Great answer! For drawing the header cell, see this other answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753282/modifying-table-headers-on-mac