# Change NSTableView Header Font Color

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, appkit

How do I change Header font size / color and other properties of NSTableHeaderView ?

Some one has already answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753282/modifying-table-headers-on-mac), but the accepted answer is outdated, since it is for Cell Based TableViews.

I am looking for a solution that would support View based NSTableView

Comment: NSTableColumn's headerCell is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately view based column headers are still unsupported (I mean not using NSTableHeaderViewCell)

Just take a look into "NSTableColumn.h" and you will see that there is following property which has a "kindof" -> not possible to use NSView.

> ```
> /* Gets and sets the headerCell associated with this NSTableColumn. 'cell' must be non nil, and should be a member of the
> ```
>
> NSTableHeaderCell class. The 'headerCell' is a strong reference, and
>   will be retained.
>        */

```
@property (strong) __kindof NSTableHeaderCell *headerCell;
```

The only way to achieve what you need is to set properties on NSTableHeaderCell which is a subclass of "NSTextFieldCell".